# wxPython and MDI like app

Tags: python, wxpython, mdi

I want to build an application in wxPython which have multiple windows like MDI. I don't want use MDIParentFrame which is old. I've seen wx.aui too but I don't like it.

What I want is a main frame that hase a menu and toolbar and more child windows. Child windows must minimize when main frame minimize and got focus when main frame clicked

How do this ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You either use one of the MDI implementations that wxPython already has built-in or you reinvent the wheel and create your own widgets.